# парсер Python. автоматическое формирование URL

Tags: python, django, парсер, url

Суть вопроса следующая. я пишу сайт - парсер других сайтов с вакансиями на пайтоне, Django. и мне нужно чтобы при выборе пользователем города и поискового запроса автоматически формировался URL для парсинга.
Например, он хочет найти вакансии в москве по запросу python. адрес будет следующим: https://....ru/.../vacancy?area=1&text=python
area=1 на данном сайте означает поиск по Москве
Так вот я прошу совета, как все это сделать, чтобы вручную не заходить на каждый сайт и в каждый город,
может где-то на сайте можно найти эти данные?
и как их лучше хранить? я предполагаю, что в словаре:

```
Moscow = {"..1..ru/": "area=1", "..2..ru/": "city_id=678"}
```

или может быть создать отдельную таблицу в БД?

P.S. я новичок в этом, не судите строго

Comment: _"Может где-то на сайте можно найти эти данные?"_ —, может. Но как мы узнаем, если Вы не привели ссылку на сайт? Сами данные я бы хранил в БД, но если её нет, то пойдёт и словарь.

Comment: @nomnoms12 планируется несколько сайтов, мне бы узнать алгоритм поиска. например, пусть будет hh.ru. куда вообще лезть?

Comment: Лезть в `HTML`-код страницы. Конкретно у hh.ru в расширенной форме поиска каждому чекбоксу присвоено значение. Оно записано и в теге `input` (в атрибуте `value`) и в `div`'е выше (атрибут `data-id`). Всё зависит от реализации конкретного сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю алгоритм в твоем случае такой - открываешь расширенную форму поиска, открываешь логи браузера и смотришь куда он в итоге лезет при поиске, при выборе дополнительных параметров.